# Excel: Based on value of cell in column A (three possible values), and cell in column B (integer), determine the value of cell C

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to work out a problem as follows:

1. Column A: one of three possible values. {apples, oranges, pears}
2. Column B: an integer.
3. The value of column C should be calculated based on the previous two columns.

For column B, it needs to between a range of numbers. E.g. (1-19, 20-99). So, for apples, if the number is between 1 - 19, the value should be 12, if the number is between 20 and 99, the value should be 4, greater than that, the value should be 18.

The ranges and values to be output are different for each of the fruits.

At the moment, the best I can do is a long chain of nested if statements, which I don't think is optimal.

```
=IF(I74=Reference!$A$2,(IF(AND(H74>=1,H74<=19),Reference!$B$4,IF(AND(H74>=20,H74<=149), Reference!$C$4,IF(H74>=150,Reference!$D$4,"NaN")))),(IF(AND(H74>=1,H74<=19),Reference!$B$8,IF(AND(H74>=19,H74<=99), Reference!$C$8, IF(H74>=100, Reference!$D$8, "NaN")))))
```

I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to make a "item, quantity, price" table?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a reference table describing the limit quantity of each item, and sort the quantity `DESCENDING`.

Here you go:

[image]

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$4, MATCH(1, (F2 = $A$2:$A$4) * (G2 > $B$2:$B$4), 0))
```

and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the Array Formula.

### Explanation

`$C$2:$C$4` is the range of price reference.

Because we have two criteria to lookup for, use `MATCH(1, (criteria1) * (criteria2) * (...), 0)`. The formula is analogous to `MATCH(TRUE, criteria1 AND criteria2 AND ...)`.

So basically the `MATCH` lookup for the item name on the table, and quantity limit lower than quantity value.

In my example I only put `apples` on the reference table. You should add your `oranges` and `pears` yourself, obviously.